# Why is this community so elitist?

Tags: discussion

Every question you ask gets showered with people pointing and berating. This is the most toxic Stack Exchange community I've experienced. Better chances on Reddit.

Comment: It is a well-known underhanded technique to ask why X is the case, when there is actually little or no evidence that it is actually the case. Alternatives to “underhanded” are “dishonest”, “being a troll” and so on.

Comment: You have asked one question. I'm not sure how you are able to determine that every question you ask generates this response. Are you using multiple accounts?

Comment: You're disillusioned now... You were hoping for a Magic-8 Ball; I know. But it gets better; the real thing is better in the long run.

Comment: @KannE - yes in the long run, but I do still see sort of “unfriendly” attitude to new users from time to time despite rules suggest a softer tone with them. Probably Mr. ferOx is one of those.

Comment: @gnasher729 - Um, *underhanded* on a public forum...publicly underhanded. Here's a technique, name-calling by proxy: *underhanded technique, dishonest technique, being-a-troll technique...* Wait, something went wrong there. Hmm, thinking, surreptitiously, in secret; shh, don't tell anybody... Ah-ha! To-be! Always the culprit. Screws up errythang.

Comment: @user66974 - Yep, but you have to hang in there to see it through. It's easier to quit, but then you would lose all the good, a whole lotta good, with the bad... This is not POW training; let's keep it in perspective. Three years ago, I could barely speak, couldn't find my nouns... Now I have more words than ever, too many probably, but this is more than a hobby. It's also a public service, for real, and that is always evolving...requires input from people continually, and that is a good thing on the whole.

Answer (score 15):

It is a common human error to suppose that correction of an error, reasoned disagreement with an opinion, careful explanation of a criticism, or helpful reference to alternative sources are personal criticisms.

This site aims to help people by doing all or any of these things in an atmosphere of robust debate and mutual self-improvement; you seem to have fallen into the trap of thinking them directed at you personally rather than at the modes of thought.

If I dispute your opinion or I ask you to back up argument with evidence I am trying to help you improve your knowledge, strengthen your viewpoint, or engage in reasoned debate; I may even hope to learn from you; I am not insulting you.

In general, people on this site do not criticise the way you eat asparagus. To do so would indeed be an insult:

> In "Code of the Woosters" Gussie has insulted Spode in a notebook, writing that Spode's mustache was "*like the faint discoloured smear left by a squashed blackbeetle on the side of a kitchen sink", and that the way Spode eats asparagus "alters one's whole conception of Man as Nature's last word.*"
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roderick_Spode)

Comment: You believe that b/c you're respectful and helpful all the time, to practically everybody. I don't think I'm overstating that.

Comment: @KannE Well thankyou most sincerely, I admit I don't always feel quite so philanthropic as I would like to, but nevertheless your comment has made my day.

Comment: @user294180 sorry. My reply comment for KannE applies to you!

Answer (score 11):

Looking at the information given at the Help Center, one sees that the site is aimed at linguists, those with a certain proficiency in the language. Other sites are available if people want to ask more basic (ELL.SE), or English- but not specifically language-orientated (eg Literature.SE, Interpersonal Skills.SE, Writing.SE ...) questions. Language Learning.SE and Linguistics.SE are not merely English-language-specific.   Guidance on how good questions should be framed (with reasonable research in most cases), and on what constitutes a good and on-topic question, is given.

There are close-vote privileges given to those who, over time, have been awarded sufficient 'reputation' status. Often, such contributors feel it would be helpful to point out the reason they close-vote, rather than leave someone wondering. Sometimes, answers to off-topic questions are added in 'comments', as people often want to help while not encouraging such questions.

And with on-topic questions, answers may be challenged, or clarification sought. This is debate, not personal invective.